# C# - New to arrays, need clarification

Tags: c#

```
namespace Program
{
    class Path
    {
      private readonly MapLocation[] _path; 

      public Path(MapLocation[] path)
       {
          _path = path;
       } 
    }
}
```

I am having trouble understanding `_path = path;` How does one go about understanding how this works and why it's needed?

Comment: It is a `readonly` field constructor assignment. By default classes have a parameterless constructor, you're declaring a constructor method with `MapLocation` array as parameter and assign it to `readonly` field. It is required to assign `readonly` value in constructor since `readonly` value only assignable on its declaration or in a class constructor during initialization.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ColeConnelly I'd say it does. To rephrase what Yamamoto san said, a readonly field (_path) can only be assigned to in the class's constructor. After that, other methods can read it, but not write it. The parameter to the constructor, path, is only accessible in the constructor. You can't use it elsewhere, so you need to declare a variable (_path) at the class instance level, so that the data is accessible to other methods/properties in the class. Readonly ensures that the reference can't be changed after the class is instantiated.

Comment: @ColeConnelly I edited my answer to clarify things even further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Path
{
  private readonly MapLocation[] B; 

  public Path(MapLocation[] A)
   {
      B = A;
   } 
}
```

Basically you are assigning the array **path** that is passed in by the constructor to the variable _path, in the example above I have renamed them **A** and **B**, so it is assigning the array of **maplocations** from the constructor to the object variable (**B**) for storage.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to understand here so let's take it one step at a time.

**Value Types vs Reference Types**

Value Types:

In C#, some things are passed by value while others are passed by reference. Here is an example of something passed by value:

```
class Path
{
   private int _number; 

   public Path(int number)
   {
      _number = number;
   } 
}
```

Here is how we would use the above class:

```
int number = 5;
Path p1 = new Path(number);
```

The variable `number` is passed by value. What that means is: A copy of the value of what is stored in `number` is passed to the `p1` object. Therefore, if you change the value of it within the `Path` class, the value of `number` which we pass will not change. It will only change within `p1` object. Please read more on [C# value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types).

Reference Types:

Arrays are one of the things which are passed by reference in C#. Here is an example of that. I will explain `readonly` later on:

```
class Path
{
   private readonly MapLocation[] _path; 

   public Path(MapLocation[] path)
   {
      _path = path;
   } 
}
```

Here is how we would use the above class:

```
// 2 is max number of items for this array
MapLocation[] locations = new MapLoations[2];  
locations[0] = new MapLocation();
Path p1 = new Path(locations);
```

The variable `locations` is passed by reference. What that means is: A reference to the memory location of where `locations` is stored, is passed to the `p1` object. Therefore, if you change the value of it within the `Path` class, for example, if you add another item to the array, you will notice the change in `locations`. Why? Because you passed a reference to the memory location of `locations` and thus whoever (for example `Path`) has access to it, they can change things at that location. Please read more on [C# Reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). So what is happening is we pass the reference of `locations` to the `Path` constructor, and within the constructor it is assigned to the `_path` variable.

The easiest way to understand reference types is to imagine you are *passing a rope which is tied to the memory location. Anyone who has the rope, can find their way to the memory location and change it*. So in our example we create a variable named `locations` and then we tie a *rope* to it. We pass the other end of the rope to the `Path` constructor, and within the constructor the *rope* is passed to the `_path` variable. Now from within the class you can use the rope called `_path` and find the memory location all the way to `locations`. This rope can span many classes and methods and so on. Anyhow enough with the rope.

So what is the `readonly` for? This means that assignment to the variable can only happen from within the constructor and nowhere else. So in your example, `_path` can only be assigned to from within the constructor of the class where it appears which is `Path` in this case. But you ask why would someone want to do this? Well sometime you want to create a class, assign something to the variable, and then you never want to allow anyone to assign to it again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What has reference- and value-types got to do with the question?

Comment: @ColeConnelly If the answers are not sufficient, I recommend rephrashing your question. If your first language is not C#, you should tell us what your first language is and your expectations of how things should work / why this is confusing for you.

Comment: @enigmativity the question is *I am having trouble understanding _path = path; How does one go about understanding how this works and why it's needed?* So I figured understanding value vs reference type will help one understand.

Answer (score 0):

`Path` is a class. Outside of the class, you can create one or more objects of type `Path`.

Each `Path` object has a private reference to an array of `MapLocation` objects. This array reference is called `_path`.

When a `Path` object is constructed, another reference to an array of `MapLocation` objects is passed into the `Path()` constructor as an argument called `path`. Probably the expectation is that the referenced array already contains some `MapLocation` objects.

The purpose of the line of code you're asking about is to make `_path` reference the same MapLocation array as `path` does. So that the new instance of `Path` that's getting created will have be able to access/use that array.